# Make table dialog content scrollable

Tags: html, css, dialog, html-table

I have a dialog that is set up like this:

```
<div style="position:fixed; display:block; width:600px; top:0; left:50%;margin-left:-275px;">
  <table style="width:100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">×</span>
            <h2>Modal Header</h2>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color:gray;">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>variable length really long stuff</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Right now, the content of the dialog is too long for the page, and because the position is fixed, the user can never scroll down to the bottom of the dialog. I would like the inner table to be scrollable only when the length of the content exceeds the viewport area - but I would always like the header and footer to be visible.

[Here is a code sample.](http://codepen.io/coolguyxp/pen/grxZON) How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want the modal to be always 100% height? Is the header and footer fixed height?

Comment: @Pangloss The modal should only be at most as tall as the content within it, but the content should be scrollable if it can't fit in one page. Yes, the header and footer are a fixed height but the modal content changes depending on the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay using `vh` units, you could force the `modal-body` to scroll:

```
.modal-body {
   padding: 2px 16px;
   overflow:auto;
   max-height: calc(100vh - 144px); /* 144px represents the combined height of the modal header and footer */
}
```

If you don't want to use `vh` units, then you might need to programmatically toggle the overflow on the `body` when the modal comes up. You might also want to manually set the scrollTop position when changing the overflow so the page doesn't jump around.

Comment: Hi! That answer works great, but I'm going to wait and see if anyone else has any ideas - it's going to be a pain to get `calc` and `vh` approved for use.

Comment: I can understand the `vh` units, which is why I pointed that out. `calc` is supported pretty widely, but I'm guessing you need IE9 or below since you made that comment. If you wanted to use this with a graceful fallback, you could quite easily use JavaScript to calculate the appropriate max-height and set that whenever the modal is opened or whenever the browser is resized/orientationchanged.